# For $1\leq n\leq 100$ how many integers are there such that $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is a repeating decimal?

Tags: number-theory

> For $1\leq n\leq 100$ how many integers are there such that $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is a repeating decimal?

I can't figure out how to solve the question. I have no idea how to solve it without listing everything out.

Comment: What is a "repeating decimal"? A rational number with a purely periodic decimal representation?

Comment: Does $\frac{13}{14}=0.9\overline{285714}$ count even though its is only *eventually* repeating? Does $\frac 45=0.8\overline 0$ count as repeating decimal even hough it is just $0$ repeating?

Comment: @Houdineo Are you referring to numbers like $2/3,5/6$ etc.?

Comment: Until you clarify the question, it is unclear. Please edit your question.

Comment: I think what the questions means are like 2/3 and 5.6 as "repeating decimals".

Comment: I know the term "periodic decimals". But here is what I have found in Wolfram MathWorld: 

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RepeatingDecimal.html

Comment: Note that $\forall{n\in\mathbb{N}}:\gcd(n,n+1)=1$. Therefore, the only cases of $\frac{n}{n+1}$ being a **non-repeating** decimal (i.e., a number with a finite decimal representation), are when **all** the prime factors of $n+1$ are also prime factors of $10$. This is true for $n+1=2,4,5,8,10,16,20,25,32,40,50,64,80,100$.

Comment: so, n+1 has to equal a multiple of ten??

Comment: @Houdineo: No. Take $30$ for example, it has $3$ as a prime factor. And by the way, you need all the **other** values.

Comment: 10, 50, is that it?

Comment: @Houdineo: NO!!! Please read my comment carefully. There is also an answer now saying more or less the same thing.

Comment: The only cases where $\frac{n}{n+1}$ has a finite decimal expansion is when $n+1=2^i5^j$ for some $i, j \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to assume a repeating decimal is a decimal that has a part that repeats infinitely ( a number of the form $a.b\overline{c}$ ), in other words a rational number whose decimal representation does not terminate.

A rational number expressed as a reduced fracition is a repeating decimal if and only if the denominator is not of the form $2^a5^b$. Since $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is already a reduced fraction because $n$ and $n+1$ are co-prime, this is equivalent to asking $n+1$ to not be of the form $2^a5^b$.

How many numbers between $2$ and $101$ are of the form $2^a5^b$?

When $b=0$ they are $2,4,8,16,32,64$

When $b=1$ they are $5,10,20,40,80$

when $b=2$ they are $25,50,100$.

So in total there are $14$ undesired values for $n+1$. Therefore there are $86$ values where $n+1$ is not of the form $2^a5^b$. So we have $86$ repeating decimals.

Comment: You're missing $n+1=5$.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks.

Comment: Ah, so the answer should be 88?

Comment: @Houdineo: $100-14=86$!!!

Comment: whoops, brain fart.